# How do I correctly add to an array of linked lists?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, linked-list, graph-algorithm

I am making a graph that is implemented by a linked-list and I find myself in a little confusion because I'm sure I am not traversing the linked-lists correctly.

```
// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
typedef struct AdjListNode
{
    char data;
    int distance;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
} AdjListNode;

// A structure to represent an adjacency list
typedef struct AdjList
{
    char data;
    struct AdjListNode* head;  // pointer to head node of list
} AdjList;

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be the number of vertices in graph.
typedef struct Graph
{
    int NumberOfNodes;
    struct AdjList* array;
} Graph;
```

so I am making a graph that has an array and each of the elements of the array are heads to a linked list.

however, when I try to output all the elements it only prints the elements that are right next to the head eg:

```
A->B5
B->E6
C->A8
D->C2
E->D7
```

so there is an error while adding them to the linked list because it should be

```
A->B5->D5-C7
B->E6->E4
C->A8
D->C2->B6->A2
E->D7
```

This is a snippet of the function where it adds nodes to the graph I believe there is an error on the else statement

```
    for(i =0; i < G->NumberOfNodes ; i++)
    {
        if(G->array[i].data == from)
        { // if the letter from the primary array matches the letter that needs to be added to
            if(G->array[i].head == NULL)
            { // if the head node of the linked list is empty simply just and the element there
                G->array[i].head = malloc(sizeof(AdjListNode));
                G->array[i].head->data = to;
                G->array[i].head->distance = number;
                G->array[i].head->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {    // if the head is not empty then this will find another position for it
                AdjListNode* looker;

                looker = G->array[i].head;

                while(looker != NULL)
                {
                    looker = looker->next; // pointing to the next position
                }

                looker = malloc(sizeof(AdjListNode)); // placing the element on that position
                looker->data = to;
                looker->distance = number;
                looker->next = NULL;

                free(looker);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged it somehow?

Comment: no I dont know how to use de gdb fully... but im almos 90% sure the error is on the addEdge function, the else statement that uses the "looker" variable

Comment: thanks UniCell! for that editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
AdjListNode* looker;
looker = G->array[i].head;
while(looker != NULL){
    looker = looker->next; // pointing to the next position
}

looker = malloc(sizeof(AdjListNode)); // placing the element on that position
looker->data = to;
looker->distance = number;
looker->next = NULL;
free(looker);
```

It makes absolutely no changes to the linked list referred to by `G->array[i].head`. It walks a pointer to the end of a linked list (which has at-most one node). It then does nothing (how can it? all you have is a pointer to nothing), then simply allocates some memory, sets up the node, then promptly frees it.

If you want to chain to the tail of your linked list you have to do so by finding the last pointer in list. One way to do that is use a double pointer, which as a bonus alleviates your special-null-head case as well. Your entire for-loop at least appears to be doable as simply:

```
for(i =0; i < G->NumberOfNodes ; i++)
{
    if(G->array[i].data == from)
    {
        AdjListNode** pp = &(G->array[i].head);
        while (*pp)
            pp = &(*pp)->next;

        *pp = malloc(sizeof(**pp));
        (*pp)->data = to;
        (*pp)->distance = number;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

It is *critical* the `head` pointer in each slot is NULL before entering into this barrage, hopefully for obvious reasons.

Best of luck.

Comment: Exactly I knew something was wrong right there!
your code works perfectly. However, could you explain to me why the double pointer does it? I thought that double pointers were used for 2D arrays..

Comment: @ReynaldoGonzalez a pointer to pointer is no different than any other pointer; it holds the address of something (in this case a pointer rather than some data node). The code uses it to walk the linked list, holding the address of each pointer we want to check for NULL (including the head pointer). When the pointer addressed by our pointer-to-pointer holds NULL, we have reached the end of the list, and the pointer we're addressing is the place where it terminates. From there, we simply allocate a new node, assign it to that pointer (by dereference of `*pp`) and we're done.

Comment: thank you very much Craig. I bet you are working for really good software company. I am studying for interview questions since im graduating next year.